# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Double'

Tags: swift, string, double

```
extension CryptListTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard let searchBarText = searchBar.text else {return}
        let cryptRequest = CryptListStruct(assetID: String(searchBarText), name: String(searchBarText), typeIsCrypto: Int(searchBarText)!, dataQuoteStart: String?(searchBarText), dataQuoteEnd: String?(searchBarText), dataOrderbookStart: String?(searchBarText), dataOrderbookEnd: String?(searchBarText), dataTradeStart: String?(searchBarText), dataTradeEnd: String?(searchBarText), dataSymbolsCount: Int(searchBarText)!, volume1HrsUsd: Double(searchBarText)!, volume1DayUsd: Double(searchBarText)!, volume1MthUsd: Double(searchBarText)!, priceUsd: Double?(searchBarText), idIcon: String?(searchBarText), dataStart: String?(searchBarText), dataEnd: String?(searchBarText))
    }
}
```

I have trouble while converting doubles to string and as result, I am getting: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Double'

```
struct CryptListStruct: Decodable {

    let assetID, name: String
    let typeIsCrypto: Int
    let dataQuoteStart, dataQuoteEnd, dataOrderbookStart, dataOrderbookEnd: String?
    let dataTradeStart, dataTradeEnd: String?
    let dataSymbolsCount: Int
    let volume1HrsUsd, volume1DayUsd, volume1MthUsd: Double
    var priceUsd: Double?
    let idIcon, dataStart, dataEnd: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetID = "asset_id"
        case name
        case typeIsCrypto = "type_is_crypto"
        case dataQuoteStart = "data_quote_start"
        case dataQuoteEnd = "data_quote_end"
        case dataOrderbookStart = "data_orderbook_start"
        case dataOrderbookEnd = "data_orderbook_end"
        case dataTradeStart = "data_trade_start"
        case dataTradeEnd = "data_trade_end"
        case dataSymbolsCount = "data_symbols_count"
        case volume1HrsUsd = "volume_1hrs_usd"
        case volume1DayUsd = "volume_1day_usd"
        case volume1MthUsd = "volume_1mth_usd"
        case priceUsd = "price_usd"
        case idIcon = "id_icon"
        case dataStart = "data_start"
        case dataEnd = "data_end"
    }
}

struct WelcomeElement: Codable {
    let assetID: String
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case assetID = "asset_id"
        case url
    }
}
```

That is how CryptListStruct looks like.

Comment: In the long long line `CryptListStruct()`... You are giving a `String` value when it should be a `Double`. Which one, I dont' know, we don't know the struct. Look yourself.

Comment: `searchBarText` is already a String, so `String(searchText)` => just `searchText`. Also, you are doing some force unwrap: `Int(searchBartext)!`, it means that if it's searchBarText is for instance `3b`, it will fail and crash... Are you sure about that?

Comment: _"while converting doubles to string"_, where are you converting in your code or are you talking about the decoding of the json message?